# How to get URL relative "deepness"?

Tags: php, url, relative-path

In PHP, how would I get the URL relative indicators based on where I'm located? Examples:

```
Location                 Return

example.com              ./
example.com/sub          ../
example.com/sub/sub      ../../

...
```

Comment: Can I ask the reason you would want to?

Comment: I use a PHP-included header file with has to reference the top level stylesheets and a top-level menu, without removing the possibility for the actual page to use relative links, therefore not using base href.

Comment: Absolute paths can make your code a lot nicer, combined with environmental constants, e.g. `define('BASE_URL', 'http://example.com/')` and will still allow you to use relative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering your above example:

```
$url = 'example.com/sub/sub/';
$parts = explode('/', $url);
$parts = array_filter($parts, 'strlen');
$path = count($parts) == 1 ? './' : str_repeat('../', count($parts)-1);
```

This code ignores the empty parts and trailing slashes (e.g.: `example.com//sub/`).

Comment: Better. Much safer. Thanks :)

Comment: @Lazlo: No. You can have `parse_url` return only the path element (e.g.: `/sub/sub`), but you still have to count the slashes and remove the empty parts/trailing slashes yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't just counting the number of slashes in the url suffice. You could use [preg_match_all](https://www.php.net/preg_match_all) for that.

```
<?php
preg_match_all('/\//',$url,$matches);
echo count($matches);
?>
```

(untested code)

Comment: Without using regex. `substr_count($url, '/');`

Answer (score 1):

Um, a quick guess:

```
function getDeepness($url){
  $lvls = substr_count($url, '/');

  if(!$lvls){
    return "./";
  }

  return str_repeat("../", $lvls);
}
```

Comment: Fair enough, but how secure would that be? Are there cases where this could potentially fail?

Comment: The question is - where do you want to use this? I would suggest to use absolute paths - less hassle and doesn't look so ugly. Define a constant of a root path and then just append the working directories path.